# Replication not reflected for aws server side encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication, aws-sdk

I created S3 bucket under server side encryption so you know that key is the master default key maintained by aws itself, so replication of bucket is possible.

I enabled versioning to my source bucket and enabled cross region replication, and added rules like i have created new destination bucket and s3 replication role and region to replicate.

This also created and enabled in my source bucket. But when i upload an small kb of about 2.4 in my source bucket, it didnt get replicate in the destination. Also showing in my source bucket **replication status as Failed.**

Can anyone clear me , **what am i missing IN SSE bucket**???

When i apply replication for bucket without sse , it works fine and replicates in the destination region.

```
                      {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
                        "Statement": [
                                  {
                                   "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
                                   "Effect": "Deny",
                                   "Principal": "*",
                                    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-
                                                   buckettest1/*",
                                    "Condition": {
                                    "StringNotEquals": {
                                              "s3:x-amz-server-side-
                                                  encryption": "AES256"
                                                         }
                                                        }
                                                     },
                                     {
                                     "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
                                     "Effect": "Deny",
                                     "Principal": "*",
                                      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                                     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-
                                                 buckettest1/*",
                                         "Condition": {
                                                       "Null": {
                                     "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": 
                                                             "true"
                                                }
                                               }
                                             },
                           {
                        "Sid": "Stmt1478487207884",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                       "Principal": {
                             "AWS": [         ]                      ]
                                 },
                          "Action": "s3:*",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1"
                         },
                         {
                        "Sid": "AllowReadFromTower",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "AWS": [

                                      ]
                                        },
                                  "Action": [
                                       "s3:GetObject",
                                       "s3:ListBucket"
                              ],
                             "Resource": [
                                  "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1",
                             "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1/*"
                                    ]
                                    },
                                   {
                                "Sid": "AllowWriteFromTower",
                                 "Effect": "Allow",
                                 "Principal": {
                                 "AWS": [

                                           ]
                                            },
                                "Action": "s3:*",
                                 "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-bueckettest1",
                               "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1/*"
                                                      ]
                                                         },
    {
                          "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
                         "Effect": "Allow",
                         "Principal": {
                           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::acctid:root"
                                      },
                         "Action": "s3:*",
                        "Resource": [
                          "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1",
                          "arn:aws:s3:::useast1-nlsn-buckettest1/*"
                                                      ]
                                                }
                                                   ]
                                                         }
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post your actual bucket configuration. I assume you've setup some sort of bucket policy that requires SSE for put object operations? Your description of "SSE bucket" is vague and unclear.

Comment: hi,,i added my source bucket policy ,did i want to apply the same sse policy for destination bucket too.

Comment: Any update guys, did iam missing any policies for sse source bucket.